# Mysterium Keyboard ATmega32a malfunctioning. "USB device not recognized."

Tags: microcontroller, usb, soldering, atmega, keyboard

I tried sourcing all [the parts for this keyboard.](https://github.com/coseyfannitutti/mysterium)

I soldered everything up and when I plug in the keyboard I immediately get an error message "USB device not recognized":

[image]

My first though was that I had a cold joint somewhere (specifically on the USB-C port) but after some quick continuity checking, I think the USB-C port is fine.

My second thought that maybe since I had to switch my capacitor from [this capacitor](https://octopart.com/rder71h104k0m1h03a-murata-38816908) to a cheap one I got in my electrical engineering program that something might be off there. I don't think it should matter for this though since they are both ceramic and .1uF.

If you would like to see more of the schematic, view the github linked above. For those of you interested the schematic for the type-c port is here:

[image]

I checked the fuse and it is still good.

Ultimately I need to know if this could be software related or if there has to be something wrong with the way I worked the board. I am not sure exactly what else to check.

Comment: So, did you program the firmware to the MCU? I can't open the full schematics, but I already see that the thing uses a 5V AVR and software bitbang USB, hence the zeners for "protecting" the PC USB pins, and also the USB data pull up is to 5V. That is pretty makeshift USB interface, and if built wrong, it may damage your PC USB port. I don't get why people copy bad designs around, and people should not blindly trust random designs found on the net and plug them into their expensive computers.

Comment: What's the purpose of the 3.6 V Zener diodes?

Comment: @Justme Well luckily it is working! Is there something you would recommend to make the design safer? I would love to learn more about it.

Comment: @winny Not entirely sure to be honest. I just copied the schematic.

Comment: @winny The zeners exist to limit voltage, the MCU has 5V GPIO pins and USB data is 3.3V.

Comment: That won’t work at USB speeds and you are violating the USB spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I soldered everything up [...]

Not enough. You also need to program the µC chip.

The device is detected via th 1.5k resistor on the D- line. The error message from the OS is because the controller did not respond properly to the USB request.

Comment: Thank you! That is the conclusion that I came to. I am a bit confused. What is the difference between flashing and programming? Do I need to buy something to interface with it and program it? I think I read that I can use an arduino. In addition, what do I program it with? What software, and what firmware do I choose? This is all new to me but I would love to learn! Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Peoncup Flashing and programming are usually the same thing, unless a piece has pre-programmed bootloader firmware on it. You'd usually do this with an in-circuit debugger adapter from USB. Microchips site for the specific part no doubt lists a bunch of them that you could use.

Comment: @Lundin Sorry another question. Am I getting the error because I haven't programmed the chip or is that an entirely different issue?

Comment: Basically I don't know how to program it since I can't get the computer to recognize it...

Comment: You need a special piece of hardware that has USB on one side and and ISP on the other - that is why there is an ISP port on the schematic. This is the interface you are supposed to use in order to flash the µC. ISP = In System Programming
Note: You need an AVR-specific one. Avoiding product names for TOS reasons here.

Comment: So I bought a programmer that goes from usb to 6pin output presumably for programming. Unfortunately the guides they have seem to be over my head. How do I use the programmer to make my keyboard recognizable to Windows so that I can use the .hex file to make it behave like a keyboard.

Comment: Use google. There are books that explain how to program microcontrollers like the Atmega32A. This forum does not allow posts to be long enough in order to properly explain programming to a beginner.

Comment: I will keep googling.